# Is it possible to pack a struct in C to size defined by bits

Tags: c, struct, padding, packing

I have the following struct

```
struct header {
    unsigned int op:16;
    unsigned int A:1;
    unsigned int B:1;
    unsigned int C:1;
    unsigned int pad:1;
}

int main() {
    struct header a;
     printf("size of header is: %lu\n", sizeof(a));

    return 0;
}
```

output is `size of header is: 4`

If I use `__attribute__((__packed__))`

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) header {
    unsigned int op:16;
    unsigned int A:1;
    unsigned int B:1;
    unsigned int C:1;
    unsigned int pad:1;
}

int main() {
    struct header a;
    printf("size of header is: %lu\n", sizeof(a));

    return 0;
}
```

output is `size of header is: 3`

Is there a way to avoid the padding to 3 bytes? Can I take only the required 20 bits?
One of the reason I need this is for converting the struct to a hex number e.g

```
struct header test1, test2;
test1.op = 1;
test1.A = 0;
test1.B = 1
test1.C = 0;
test1.pad = 0;

test2.op = 1024;
test2.A = 0;
test2.B = 1
test2.C = 1;
test2.pad = 0;
```

is converted to `0x20001` and `0x60400` respectively and would like to avoid the need to remove the padding if possible

Comment: If you need a hex number, stop using bit-fields and just use an `uint32_t`.  That's also portable, something bit-fields are not.

Comment: Why does it make a difference if you use 20 bits or 24 bits? Why do you care? `One of the reason I need this is for converting the struct to a hex numbe` I do not understand, how is that a reason? `is converted` C does not come with "auto-convert-struct-to-hex" utility. _How_ are _you_ converting the struct into `0x20001` representation? Please post _your_ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to pack a struct in C to size defined by bits

No.

> Is there a way to avoid the padding to 3 bytes?

No.

> Can I take only the required 20 bits?

No.

The *smallest addressable unit* is a byte. Everything in C has to be a multiple of a byte.

(Theoretically, you could use a compiler (or re-compile GCC) with a byte having 10 bits, then your struct would take exactly 2 bytes. That would be tedious, non-portable and I would say ridiculous). However, on any modern platform, a byte has 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

C 2018 6.2.6 2 says:

> Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes,…

Therefore, a structure, which is not a bit-field even if it is composed solely of bit-fields, must be composed of a whole number of bytes.

(A C implementation could extend the C standard by allowing some objects to be a fractional number of bytes, but I am not aware of any C implementation that does this.)